# Run different macros for two different sheets in same workbook using python

Tags: python, vba

Below is the code I have for running macro for two different sheets in same excel file using python...

```
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Trial.xlsm').sheets['Sheet1']
macro1= wb.macro("Module1.dwell")
macro1()

ws = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Trial.xlsm').sheets['Sheet2']
macro2= ws.macro("Module2.hide")
macro2()


wb.save(r'C:\Users\Trial.xlsm')
ws.save(r'C:\Users\Trial.xlsm')
wb.close()
ws.close()
```

This code does not run any macro saved in the excel workbook. But without mentioning any sheet name, all  macros are running for sheet 1 .... which I dont want

I just want to run macro 1 for sheet 1 and macro 2 for sheet 2... Is there any way.?

Comment: How do the macros in the _modules_ look like? Maybe they "work" on the active worksheet.

Comment: I created modules under separate sheet..  even then its not helping

Comment: Have you created modules (which afaik can note be located in a sheet) with your code, or  the code in different sheets?

Comment: I created modules in the excel file clicking on sheet names and trying to call out the module to run using python.